# How to easily remove fields from Redux form and Redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

My code uses conditional rendering to remove fields from form DOM. For redux form, the deleted field value will remain in the form store, and this is really annoying. Anyone has good ideas how to solve this issue? The following is my implementation for the conditional rendering. Because it is quite common in my project to do the conditional rendering, how can I solve the issue glablly?

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Field, getFormValues } from "redux-form";
import { Grid, Form } from "semantic-ui-react";
import RenderFieldSelect from "../../formElements/Select";

import {
  PROPERTY_TYPE_1,
  PROPERTY_TYPE_2,
  SUB_TYPE,
  EMPTY_OPTIONS
} from "./SelectOptions";
import { required } from "redux-form-validators";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class SummaryAttributes extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let propertyType; // property type
    let propertyTypes = EMPTY_OPTIONS; // propertyTypes options
    let hasSubType; 
    let subTypes = EMPTY_OPTIONS; 

    const { formValues } = this.props;

    if (formValues !== undefined) {
      const { scorecardType } = this.props.match.params;
      switch (scorecardType) {
        case "1":
          propertyTypes = PROPERTY_TYPE_1;
          break;
        case "2":
          propertyTypes = PROPERTY_TYPE_2;
          break;
        default:
      }

      propertyType = formValues.propertyType;
      switch (propertyType) {
        case "1":
          subTypes = SUB_TYPE;
          hasSubType = true;
          break;
        case "2":
          hasSubType = false;
          break;
        default:
          subTypes = SUB_TYPE;
          hasSubType = true;
      }
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Grid>
          <Grid.Row columns="equal">
            <Grid.Column>
              <Form.Group widths="equal">
                <Field
                  name="propertyType"
                  component={RenderFieldSelect}
                  label="Property Type"
                  required="Y"
                  options={propertyTypes}
                  validate={[required()]}
                />
              </Form.Group>
            </Grid.Column>
            <Grid.Column>
              {hasSubType && (
                <Field
                  name="subType"
                  component={RenderFieldSelect}
                  label="Sub Type"
                  required="Y"
                  options={subTypes}
                  validate={[required()]}
                />
              )}
            </Grid.Column>
          </Grid.Row>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  formValues: getFormValues("propertyForm")(state)
});

export default withRouter(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    null
  )(SummaryAttributes)
);
```

Reducer: Index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';
import loadingReducer from './reducer_loading';

export default combineReducers({
  form: formReducer,
  loading: loadingReducer
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't be too complicated. Can you show us some code from your redux?

Comment: @acdcjunior. I have updated my post.

Comment: @PLee - Please share the relevant reducer so we can have more information about your form state management.

Comment: @jank. I am using the formReducer from redux-form to get the form status. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to solve this issue:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import {
  reducer as formReducer,
  actionTypes as formActionTypes
} from "redux-form";

const removeUnregisteredFormFieldValue = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type !== formActionTypes.UNREGISTER_FIELD) return state;
  const {
    values: { [action.payload.name]: unregistered, ...values }
  } = state;
  return { ...state, values };
};

export default combineReducers({
  form: formReducer.plugin({
    sampleForm: removeUnregisteredFormFieldValue,
    propertyForm: removeUnregisteredFormFieldValue
  })
});
```